# vim frozen when using spell keyword auto-complete

Tags: vim

I am using vim's spell dictionary feature, and add these lines to my .vimrc
    set dictionary=~/.vim/dict/en_US.dic
    set complete+=k

Then I open vim and input `le`, then input `<ctrl+x>` and `<ctrl+k>`. The auto complete show up correctly.
But when I delete le to null, the vim screen is frozen.
It seems vim keep scan dictionary and try to show all words in dictionary into the screen.
After about 3 minutes, vim will come back and show up a list of words.

screen copy as following:
[image: open vim and input le, and invoke auto complete]
[image: then delete all input chars, will get vim screen frozen]
[image: after about 3 minutes, vim will come back]

Anyone know how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 9):

You can try to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> to interrupt the search for suggestion.

It works for most of the long processes freezing Vim.

There is also a `spellsuggest` option that you can use to limit the size of the suggestion list. Using 10 as a max value might speed up the process at the cost of less results found.

Comment: [CTRL-C] works for me, it will add a extra string, " =<SNR>17_RestoreVE()", to the current document. And ":set spellsuggest =5" seem not work, I still got a very long list.